# Convert date and time from api make time go ahead

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

in to another time. I want to convert the

```
<table>

        <tr>
            <th>Test:</th>
            <th>test2:</th>
        </tr>


<table>
```

Comment: `dt_txt` is a string or a `Date` object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should also mention the format or a sample of what is exactly coming in the "dt_txt" variable.

However, it is a string you could always parse the string and split it into different parts and update each part as per your need and then join them again. Since it is a list you can do that in a loop when your data gets loaded.

Example:

```js
var temp = "11/2/2018 09:00";
var time = temp.split(" ")[1];
var hrs = parseInt(time.split(":")[0]);
hrs++;
```

Comment: Please modify your answer, dates don't work like this. For example, what happens when the datetime is 11/2/2018 23:30:00?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a pipe which adds an extra hour to the date and returns a string in your concatenated with an `&`.

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'dateAdd'
})
export class DateAddPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: string | Date): string {
    // if it was a string date
    let oldDate = new Date(value);

    // add one extra hour to the existing date
    oldDate.setHours(oldDate.getHours() + 1);

    // I am manually restricting you with a format like MM-DD-YYYY
    // create your own format, or accept another argument and use a date library like moment to convert to your required format if you have a multi format requirement
    let onlyDate = ('0' + (oldDate.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '-' + ('0' + oldDate.getDate()).slice(-2) + '-' + oldDate.getFullYear();

    let onlyTime = ('0' + oldDate.getHours()).slice(-2) + ":" + ('0' + oldDate.getMinutes()).slice(-2) + ":" + ('0' + oldDate.getSeconds()).slice(-2);

    return onlyDate + ' & ' + onlyTime
  }

}
```

Use it like:

```
<td>{{forecastInfo.list[4].dt_txt | dateAdd}}</td>
```

Comment: I will try to make this pipe